# python: how to assign python variable value to textbox and vice versa

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, textbox

I'm using `python 2.7`, i want to display my variable value in html `textbox` and also i want to get textbox input to `python variable`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb
import cgi

import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

description="1 watt led"
serial_no="uyt-1237"

print "content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '/head>'
print '<body>'
print '<table>'
print '<tr>'
print '<td>'
print '<label class="label">Serial Num Option:</label>'
print '</td>'
print '<td>'
print '<select class="textbox">'
print '<option value="serialno">Serial Num Auto Generate</option>'
print '<option value="barcode">Barcode Scanner Capture</option>'
print '</select>'
print '</td>'
print '<td>'
print '<label class="label">Serial Num:</label>'
print '</td>'
print '<td>'
print '<input class="textbox" type="text" name="serial" id="serial"/>'
print '</td>'
print '<td>'
print '<label class="label">PartNum:</label>'
print '</td>'
print '<td>'
print '<select class="textbox">'
print '<option value=""></option>'
print '</select>'
print '</td>'
print '</tr>'
print '<tr>'
print '<td>'
print '<label class="label">Revision No:</label>'
print '</td>'
print '<td>'
print '<select class="textbox">'
print '<option value=""></option>'
print '</select>'
print '</td>'
print '<td>'
print '<label class="label">Description:</label>'
print '</td>'
print '<td>'
print '<input class="textbox" type="text" name="description" id="description"/>'
print '</td>'
print '</tr>'
print '</table>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

i have two `python` variables `description` and `serial_no` now i want to display these two variable data in `textboxes`.

please help me it's very important....

Comment: Mother of god... I very strongly recommend taking a look at Flask or some other web framework. Or at the very least the Jinja2 templating library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Store Variable Value to TextBox:

```
 print '<input type="text" name="serial" value="%s" >' %(serial_no)

 print '<input type="text" name="description" value="%s">' %(description)
```

To Store TextBox value to Variable:

```
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
serial_no = form.getvalue('serial')
description = form.getvalue('description')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more of a HTML-question.
You can specify the value of an  element with value:

```
print '<input class="textbox" type="text" name="serial" id="serial" value="' + str(serial_no) + '"/>'
```

Have a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here is an HTML page that displays values returned from python in the input field:

```
        <label>Title</label><input name="title" value=
        {% if book %}
            {{ book[0][1] }}
        {% endif %}>
```

The python class which sends the value to the above page is working like this:

```
        book = helper.search_by_id(book_id)
        if len(book) == 0:
            book = None

        books = helper.fetch_all_books()
        return render_template("book_store.html", books=books, book=book)
```